# Numpy array only containing [0,0,0,1] when using imread on png file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, imread

Im using matplotlib and numpy to turn a png file (link to image: https://imgpile.com/i/boANTE) into a  2d array using this code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as mat_plot

mapimage = mat_plot.imread("map.png")


print(mapimage)
```

when I run this the output looks like this

```
 [[0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]]]
```

I don't understand why this is happening as the png file contains coloured pixels but they are not being shown in the 2d array, even though when I open the image with matplotlib and hover over coloured pixels I can see that they should have rgb values other than 0,0,0.

Comment: Your image is black around the edges, right?

Comment: Yes the image is black around the edges, would that be why?

Comment: You are only seeing a tiny percentage of the top and bottom of the image. Try printing `np.max(mapimage)`

Comment: When I print np.max(mapimage) the program prints "1.0" when it is run.

Comment: Cool, so you don’t need to worry. You have values between 0..1 exactly as expected.

Comment: I expected values between 0 and 1 but I don't understand why every RGB value is 0 where there are pixels in the image which are in colour. This is especially troublesome as I need to try and identify all the red pixels in the image and output them along with another 2d array.

Comment: There is no place on your console to print all the pixels values. What you see (hence the `...` in your prints) are just a few samples of the pixels of the image. Namely the 3 first and the 3 last pixels of the 3 first and 3 last lines of your image (you shown only an even smaller extract of that). So, that are just the pixels of each corners of your image. And the corner of your image are black.